# QGIS Numerical Vertex Edit - anyone else finding it doesn't work?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

The QGIS Numerical Vertex Edit plug-in used to work fine, but stopped working for me around about QGIS 2.6. I now use QGIS 2.8.1 Windows 64 bit.

The plug-in no longer seems able to see points or vertices on editable layers. Instead, it reports a Python code error: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'toBool'".

Uninstalling and re-installing the plug-in has no effect.

Is this just me being silly, or is it a problem others are finding too?

Comment: The Numerical Vertex Edit Plugin has now been updated in the 
QGIS Python Plugins Repository to Version 0.2.1. This is now working fine in QGIS 2.8.1 (on Windows 7), and the problem described above no longer occurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the project homepage, [you are not the first one](http://sourceforge.net/projects/geoing/) to notice this. Please note that gis.se is not a bugtracker and it is unlikely that this post here will help to fix this issue.

Therefore, please use one or more of the following options to proceed

- Create a ticker in the plugin bugtracker
- Contact the plugin author
- Consider funding him to fix it (or if he does not want to contract somebody else)
- Fix the code yourself and send it to the plugin author (if it was on github like many other projects that would be a pull request)
- If everything else fails, ask for transfer of maintainership or start a fork

As an alternative approach you can also try the [Plain Geometry Editor](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plaingeometryeditor/) plugin ([Demo Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9-ygwMw72Ww)).

Comment: Thanks for the link to a generalised review. The specific  error was reported back in Dec 2013, https://hub.qgis.org/issues/9540 . This related to QGIS version 2.0.1 and the status of the bug report was set to 'closed', with something about the resolution being 'invalid'. I can find little else about this plugin error, so possibly nobody else uses the plugin. I have no programming skills and I am not a commercial user, so the suggested options here are out of my league. I will use MapInfo instead.

Comment: IanS, the answer in the bug you linked says "Please file bugs in that plugin at http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/geoing/". This is the same as the first point in my answer. It requires neither programming skills nor financial resources.

Comment: Added a link to a similar alternative plugin...

Comment: Thank you Matthias for the link to the Plain Geometry Editor plug-in. This works well, and can supplant the Numerical Vertex Edit plug-in. Problem solved, I am happy with that.

Just on bug reporting for Numerical Vertex Edit, there seems to be nowhere for bug reporting on the Sourceforge page that you linked to. I left a new review there instead.