# Point Sampler Python Error in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python

I downloaded the point sampling tool for QGIS and I'm trying to run it. A few days ago it worked fine, but now it gives the following error:

An error has occured while executing Python code:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:...pointsamplingtool    \doPointSamplingTool.py", line 262, in accept
>
> ```
>    self.sampling(outPath)
> ```
>
> File "C:....pointsamplingtool\doPointSamplingTool.py", line 315, in sampling
>
> ```
>    if pointGeom.wkbType() == QGis.WKBMultiPoint:
> ```
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'wkbType'

Python version:
2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

QGIS version:
2.10.1-Pisa Pisa, d20c5b7

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: What are your points stored as? Data type? There is something wrong with them.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same I was trying to get point sample working in data extracted from CSV file and raster file 
**Solved by**:

Saving the data from CSV file as shapefile then create the point sampling against the shapefile and the raster data and it worked fine .

hope this help u :)

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in the plugin. I would suggest to open an [issue report](https://github.com/borysiasty/pointsamplingtool). Please note that gis.se is not a bugtracker and it is unlikely that this post here will help to fix this issue.

For further possibilities to proceed, please have a look at [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144852/qgis-numerical-vertex-edit-anyone-else-finding-it-doesnt-work/144864#144864).

Comment: Thanks - was hoping that somebody else would have had the problem and know how to fix it.